# How to get code working with F5 - works fine with F8

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code in excel works with F8 but doesn't with F5.
Here below you see my code.

```
Sub CheckFileExists()

'Clear content
Windows("FilesExists.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("FilesExists").Select
    Range("C50").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C50").Select

Windows("FilesExists.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("FilesExists").Select
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FilesExists")
    
Dim webURL As String
Numrows = Range("B50", Range("B50").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("B50").Select

With ws
For x = 1 To Numrows
    'delay (3)
    CurrValue = ActiveCell.Value
    webURL = CurrValue
    If IsURLGood(webURL) = True Then
        .Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "EXISTS"
    Else
        .Range("C" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "CHECK"
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End With
'Improves performance/stability
Call OptimizeCode_End

End Sub

Public Function IsURLGood(URL As String) As Boolean 'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim WinHttpReq_Today As Object
    Set WinHttpReq_Today = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    
    On Error GoTo IsURLGoodError
    WinHttpReq_Today.Open "HEAD", URL
    WinHttpReq_Today.send
    If WinHttpReq_Today.Status = 200 Then
        IsURLGood = True
    Else
        IsURLGood = False
    End If
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Function
    
IsURLGoodError:
    IsURLGood = False
    'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Function
```

I really hope someone can help, so I will be able to setup automatical execution forwarding a daily mail with whether files exists. Thnaks in advance ;-)

Kind regards
Soren Sig Mikkelsen

Comment: Get rid of the Windows statements and then learn how to qualify your spreadsheets by workbook.worksheet (e.g. workbook.worksheet.Range  etc.)

Comment: I have now tried to get rid of the Windows statements, but still doesn't work.
You can see under answers what I have tried. What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HTTP Request (`GET`)

```vb
Sub CheckFileExists()

Dim dT As Double: dT = Timer

    Const WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "FileExists"
    Const SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B50"
    Const DESTINATION_COLUMN_STRING As String = "C"
    Const YES_STRING As String = "EXISTS"
    Const NO_STRING As String = "CHECK"
    Const PRINT_MESSAGE As Boolean = False
    Const PRINT_MESSAGE_IF_OK As Boolean = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(WORKSHEET_NAME)
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False 

    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = SetColumn(ws.Range(SOURCE_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS))
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = GetColumn(srg)

    Dim r As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim UrlExists As Boolean

    For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        URL = CStr(Data(r, 1))
        If Len(URL) > 0 Then
            If IsUrlGood(URL, PRINT_MESSAGE, PRINT_MESSAGE_IF_OK) Then
                UrlExists = True
            End If
        End If
        Data(r, 1) = IIf(UrlExists, YES_STRING, NO_STRING)
        UrlExists = False
    Next r

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DESTINATION_COLUMN_STRING)
    drg.Value = Data

Debug.Print "Time Passed: " & Format(Timer - dT, "0.000")

End Sub


Function IsUrlGood( _
    ByVal URL As String, _
    Optional ByVal PrintMessage As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal PrintMessageIfOK As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim StatusNumber As Long
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0") ' New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 '
        .Open "HEAD", URL, False
        .send
        StatusNumber = .Status
    End With
    
    If StatusNumber = 200 Then
        IsUrlGood = True
        If PrintMessageIfOK Then Debug.Print URL, StatusNumber, "OK"
    Else
        If PrintMessage Then Debug.Print URL, StatusNumber
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    If PrintMessage Then
        Dim ED As String: ED = Err.Description: ED = Left(ED, Len(ED) - 2)
        Debug.Print URL, ED ' remove trailing 'vbCrLf' ('- 2')
    End If
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function SetColumn(ByVal FirstCellRange As Range) As Range
    With FirstCellRange
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set SetColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

Function GetColumn(ByVal OneColumnRange As Range) As Variant()
    With OneColumnRange
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then ' one cell
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = .Value: GetColumn = Data
        Else ' multiple cells
            GetColumn = .Value
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Hereby resolved. A huge thank you !!! 
Very impressive solution with triple functions in use ;-)